# With Perl on Mac - How to open a new terminal and pass through commands

Tags: macos, perl

In Perl, on a Mac, I want to open a terminal window and pass on commands to that terminal.

In a Perl script, written for windows, the line

```
 system("gnome-terminal -- perl pullauta startthread $i");
```

Will start a new terminal window and execute the command "perl pullauta..."

When adopting this to Mac I do not get it how to send the commands to the new terminal.

I can open a new terminal window with

```
system ("open -n /System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");
```

But I do not understand how to pass on the arguments / commands to the new window.

Any ideas? Given it needs to be executed from the Perl script, on a Mac.

Comment: Re "*In a Perl script, written for windows*", Not many Windows systems have Gnome installed! One would actually use `start` on Windows. Better yet, Win32::Process's `Open` with the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the terminal to run a command. You can skip that by calling the command directly:

```
system 'echo', 'Hello there';
```

If you are trying to use a particular shell, that would be your command:

```
system 'zsh', ...
```

I suspect that you don't need the gnome-terminal either, but you haven't said why you are doing it that way. Maybe you have some weird situation. I suspect that since you are on Windows, that you are trying to avoid the default CMD shell and choosing the shell you want. It's a bit more complicated over there because you have a unixy tool (perl) adapted to work in Windows which you are then trying to adapt further to a unixy environment. When you are already on a unixy system, you just skip all that.

But, if you want to control Terminal for some reason, Apple wants you to do that through AppleScript:

```
osascript -e 'tell application Terminal to do script ...'
```

Comment: I imagine it's `system 'zsh', '-c', $shell_cmd`, to be more specific.

Comment: Some more background then. I understand that might help.

The script is originally written for windows. Hence the use of Gnome-terminal. We are now trying to adopt it to run on Mac. It is written in Perl.

The original script can work as a batch tool where the same script can start multiple parallell instances of it self, typically one instance per thread possible for the CPU. The purpose of the script is to analyze data files of LIDAR. The script opens as many parallel terminal windows as you say in the input parameters to the script, and each window is given a start command.

Comment: So using system("perl", "pullauta", "startthread", "1"); in accordance with Brians suggestion starts one instance of the script the way I want it. But it occupies the terminal until it is done. 

Is it possible to force a new window with system ("perl" ... ?

I did not find a quick solution to that.

Comment: Update your original question if you have clarifications. I still don't think you need any terminal windows here. What do you think the terminal is doing for you?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what was the solution for us was to use `system('the scripts name'`)

Essentially calling the script in the same terminal window and repeating that for all batch processes. It works in the sense that we get the output wanted, but not being able to see output texts from each process in parallel windows. As long as everything executes as expected this is a working solution.